How to deal with all files have been quarantined on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.13?
My MacBook Air has recently quarantined all documents and apps on my computer. When trying to open any document (.jpeg, .pdf, .docx, .mp4, etc), I get the following prompt:

XXX is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

I have tried to open all file types I can think of and they all result in the same prompt. I can email the documents to another machine and they open fine.
I tried xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine in the terminal to remove documents from quarantine. This worked as expected, but is tedious considering how many documents I would need to do this with.
Is there any way to clear all quarantined documents and apps at once?
I tried rebooting. I have not updated to the latest OS, I need to free up some memory space to download the latest OS. I am currently on macOS 10.13.

Does it say that the file is damaged, or the app that is opening the file? The real question is "how/why did everything get quarantined?"

Does that happen qwith a newly created user?

That command is recursive. When the argument is a folder, it applies to everything inside that folder.
